# Visual Studio 2019 black bars around designer on 1440p

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I have 3 monitors connected. Two 1080p and one 1440p. If I drag VS to the 1440p, then I get those weir black edges and I cannot find a way to fix it.

Can I ask for some assistance please?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by turning off "Optimize rendering for screens with different pixel densities"

[image]